# How to block iframe cookies?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to block iframe cookies,the solution should not be browser specific, I have got to allow/block third party  cookies from getting downloaded to the users system depending on his/her consent. Is there any way this can be done.

Comment: This is not possible. Maybe you should try explaining what the real issue is. We might have a better solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javascript you can only access to cookies that are valid in your domain and path, so no way to mess with cookies from another domain that way ...