# How to block Cookies from Instagram Embedded Post?

Tags: javascript, cookies, instagram

I have some embedded Instagram posts from other people on my website.

However, I am pretty concerned with the European Data Protection legislation (GDPR) and I would like to avoid using cookies.

Is there any way I can keep those IG posts embedded but with its cookies blocked?

I just found the question [How to block iframe cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176591/how-to-block-iframe-cookies]), but it is 8 years old and not specific to Instagram.

Edit: Instagram does not use Iframe

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sandbox property, which allows third-party javascript but restricts them from reading and writing cookies.

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" src="..."></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that Instagram actually does not use iframe to embed their posts, I updated the question accordingly. Anyway, for all other embeds with frames (like Youtube), this could be very useful.
Does it always work? I tried it with some Youtube iframes, but https://www.cookieserve.com/ tells me that there are still youtube cookies on my site.

Comment: That's interesting. It's supposed to prevent the iframe from reading from or writing to the document.cookie IDL attribute, and when a sandboxed iframe attempts to write a cookie, the following exception is raised:

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'cookie' property on 'Document': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.